# Django true one-to-many not many-to-one

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to create a foreign key field referencing multiple objects and not the other way around. I want author referencing multiple books not multiple books referencing one author. I know I can create many-to-many field but it seems wasteful to me.

Comment: That is a one-to-many, specify the relationship on the author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it opposite.

```
class Author(models.Model):

    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', related_name='books')
```

Now you can access books written by author like this:

```
author_object.books.all()
```

which gives you a `QuerySet` of all books of this very author.

**EDIT:**

If there could be multiple authors of one book and author could write multiple books, then `models.ManyToManyField` is a correct way.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i need. I overlooked related_name in documentation.